# Problema con calculo de un factorial

Tags: c#, factorial

Cordial saludo

La presente es para manifestar un problema lógico del calculo de un factorial de n números el cual se pretende capturar la entrada en consola en c# del rango de números al que se desea saber su factorial, por medio de esto el programa funciona óptimamente hasta el número 13 pero de hay en adelante los números comienzan a tomar valores negativos hasta repetirse varias veces el 0, si me pudieran colaborar se los agradecería demasiado.

Muchas gracias por la atención prestada.

```
introducir el código aquí

namespace Factorial
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Factorial(int numero)
    {
        int facto = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numero; i++)
        {
            facto = facto * i;
        }
           
        Console.WriteLine("El factorial de {0} es = {1}", numero, facto);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de números :");


        int cantidad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++)
        {
            Factorial(i);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Eso puede darse por la capacidad numerica de cada tipo de datos, deberias usar valores tipo ``` float ``` que es el que mayor capacidad de almacenamiento en bits posee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo qué pasa es que el **factorial de 13** es un número muy grande que no cabe en un tipo de dato **int** ya que los **int** tienen un valor máximo de **2^32** o **2^64** para los **Int64**, para trabajar con números exageradamente grandes está la **clase BigInteger**, para trabajar con ella debes incluir la librería **System.Numerics**, dando clic derecho en **References** en el **explorador de soluciones opción Add references** ahí buscas la librería y la añades, posteriormente la pones en el **using** como:

```
using System.Numerics;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias mi amigo, funciono perfectamente, la verdad no recordaba eso puesto que hace rato que no utilizaba c#.